# Is it possible to write a plain old java program that runs on android?

Tags: java, android

I see tutorials that show you how to make a real android application with activities and all that, but all I really want to do is make a java class that has a public void static main(String params[]) { System.out.println("Hello World");}   and run it with java HelloWorld on an android machine. Is that possible?

Comment: For any production scenario, such an app would be fairly useless. If you're doing this for grins, fine.

Comment: well, I guess I'm glad you approve, this is for me and my phone. I'm a programmer and I like to tinker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a great app on the Android market called [Terminal IDE](http://www.spartacusrex.com/terminalide.htm) that includes a great shell environment, vim/nano and java/javac all compiled to run natively on Android.  With this you can run "normal" Java code.

Comment: Thanks for your thanks, but you can really thank me by accepting.  Not affiliated at with with the app, just a fellow hobbyist.

Comment: well I upvoted, and had/have every intention of marking as the answer as soon as I try it and find out that it in fact is the answer. No offense or anything, but I figure that makes more sense to people who come later and ask the same question.

Comment: Well I think we learned something here. This is in fact what I was looking for but it doesn't install on my g1, so I can't use it anyway, a lesson to others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you take the time to create a very simple Activity (which Eclipse will basically generate for you when you make a new Android application, then you will be able to create and call any class or method on that class that you so desire.

In the Activity class, there will be a method called create() - you will modify it to instantiate your class and call a desired method...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Instantiate your class or simply call its main(String[] args) method here 
}
```

There, that wasn't so hard was it?

Good Luck!

Rodney